# Problem with pagination

Tags: ee2, focus-lab-master-config, multi-language

I'm struggling with an issue with pagination on one of our sites...

We are running a multi-language site (English & French). We are using the standard method of having folders at web root (ie. en, fr, etc.). We are also removing index from the URL using the approved Ellis lab way.

```
# rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On

# ditch index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Lastly We are using the Focus Lab Config file (nothing out of the ordinary here.

The problem is that If I have a URL (http://website.com/index.php/blog) and I click the pagination link, I'm taken to the following URL (http://website.com/en/blogindex.php/P3). It adds index.php after the blog folder, not index as this is the template. secondly it removes index.php after the /en folder which for some reason it seems to need to work. The address that works is (http://website.com/en/index.php/blog/index/P3) OR (http://website.com/en/index.php/blog/P3).

I have absolutely no idea how to modify this URL, it's generated from the pagination.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the Focus Lab Multi config setup, but I wouldn't even know where to start.

Any thoughts? I'm completely baffled...

Comment: I am having the same problem but minus the multi-language issues. Just adds "index.php" after the category name and before the "/P60" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have set $assign_to_config['site_url'] in /en/index.php?

<del>I recently installed https://github.com/averyvery/Freebie to make EE ignore certain segments.</del>

**edit**
i ended up using a find/replace add-on
 - http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/find-and-replace-plus
 - or http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-replace